# Dynamically show content in a bootstrap modal with ajax is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having an issue with my code, I followed a tutorial on this but I can't seem to make it work, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Gestionnaire de stock</title>
    <link href="dist/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="dist/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="dist/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="dist/css/hover-min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="dist/js/fa.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include "includes/functions.php";
    include "menuBar.php";
    include "workersheader.php";
?>
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center containerzred">
    <h3>Liste des employés</h3><br>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher un employé">
      <br>
          <table class="table table-bordered table-light table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>N° tel</th>
                <th>Fonction</th>
                <th><center>Actions</center></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM worker";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqliCon, $query);
                while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    if ($row['type'] == "1")
                        $type="Peseur";
                    else
                        $type="Pétrisseur";
              echo'<tr class="record">
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['tel'].'</td>
                <td>'.$type.'</td>
                <td>
                <button type="button" id="modalButton" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#custModal">
                  Fiche de travail
                </button>
                <td>
              </tr>';
            //    <!-- Modal -->
                    
              echo'<div class="modal fade" id="custModal" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                  
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Customer Details</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-window-close"></i></button>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="modal-body">

                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>';
                }
            ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
</div>
<script src="dist/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="dist/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="dist/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="dist/js/datatables-demo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
 
      $('#modalButton').click(function () {
        var workerId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
          url: 'get_data.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: { workerId: workerId },
          success: function (response) {
            $('.modal-body').html(response);
            $('#custModal').modal('show');
          }
        });
      });
 
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the php page for the result, I just did this to test the result so I can work on it

```php
<?php
//echo $id = $_POST["workerId"];
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Now, my problem is whenever I click on any button (which in the inspect page shows id's correctly) I get the same id on every button even though the id's are different.
Thank you in advance and my apologies if the page styling is wrong.

Comment: You can't repeat element ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Also `<div>` is invalid child of `<tbody>`

Comment: @charlietfl I tried this instead
```
<button type="button" id="modalButton" data-workerid="'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#custModal">
```

Comment: That's not doing anything to remedy repeating id

Comment: I found the solution with the help of a friend, I only had to swap the trigger from an id to a class.